# Angularjs function meaning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in programming. I would like to understand what the beginning of this angular function is doing line by line ?

```
  function UserProfileService($http, ApiConfigService) { 
    var profileUrl = ApiConfigService.getEndpoints().user_service + 
'/v2/users/profile';
    var oauthUrl = ApiConfigService.getEndpoints().oauth_service +
'/v2/oauth';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is creating two different string variables. The base url comes from the ApiConfigService and rest is concatenated there to the baseurl.

We could assume the following:

`ApiConfigService.getEndpoints().user_service = 'http://example.com/user-service'
ApiConfigService.getEndpoints().oauth_service = 'http://example.com/oauth-service'`

then the variables here would get the following values:

`profileUrl = 'http://example.com/user-service/v2/users/profile'
oauthUrl = 'http://example.com/oauth-service/v2/oauth'`